# Tag Synonym Request: [qube] -> [q.u.b.e.]

Tags: support, status-declined, tag-synonyms

The game is actually called Q.U.B.E., so the main tag should be [q.u.b.e](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/q.u.b.e), but [qube](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qube) already exists and is easier to type.

Comment: -1, I know of no other game we've done this for

Answer (score 7):

This can't be done. The system cleans up the `q.u.b.e.` tag to `q.u.b.e` (no last dot).

Since your request is all about correct punctuation and the system doesn't allow us to do that, the tag shall remain `qube`.